# Using federations to partition for multiple tenants

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Given the following "facts" I have gleaned from reading around this.

1. Federations are separate databases from the moment they are created.
2. As copies of the original, they will not alter automatically if I alter the original's schema.
3. As separate databases you cannot cross join.
4. Each federation is priced as a separate db.
5. I will have to provide a TenantId field to each table I want to federate.

If these are correct, what are the advantages to using federation to achieve multi-tenancy over simply separate dbs? Or if there're not correct please put me straight.

Note, we have a small number of tenants, maybe 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

There are a few interesting aspects of Federations that you may find useful. First it is a relatively flexible partitioning environment. For example you can group 10 tenants into the first member, and 50 in the second, based on usage patterns of your customers. Or you could simply isolate a single customer that is using the system more than the others.

Another important concept is that you can have multiple federations per database. So you could have a Customer federation and a SalesHistory federation for example.

Last but not least you may want to read this article that discusses [connection pool fragmentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2012/02/08/connection-pool-fragmentation-scale-to-100s-of-nodes-with-federations-and-you-won-t-need-to-ever-learn-what-these-nasty-problems-are.aspx) that occurs in traditional sharding models, but is not an issue with SQL Database Federations.